# How to integrate a specific library github commit library into an Android project?

Tags: android, github, gradle

How to use a specific version (pull request, or simply specific commit) of an android library that is on github ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may go to https://jitpack.io, and type the address of the library. Then you can browser over release or commit versions.

If case of PR, you have to put the adress of the fork and select the good commit version.

Click on **get it**, and add the generated text to your project :

on you project `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and your module gradle file

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.userName:libraryName:firstTenCommitTagChars'
}
```